# Delete a record from the database

Tags: php, sql, record

I have a PHP page and when you try to delete a record it redirects to another page,
but rather than delete the record it just refreshes.

I get the `order_id` from the previous PHP page...

```
<?php
session_start();
include("confing/db.php");
include("confing/funtion.php");
require_once('stas/config.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['idart23'])){
$idses = ($_SESSION['idart23']);
$uesrnameses = ($_SESSION['username']);
$passwordses = ($_SESSION['password']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `admins` WHERE username='".$uesrnameses."'  AND id='".$idses."'");  
if($rowadmin = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    }else{
        die(header("Location: login.php"));
    }
}else{
        die(header("Location: login.php"));
}
$order_id=$_GET['ID']; 
header("Location: orders.php");
if (isset($order_id)) { 
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `ID`='$order_id'  ");  
$time = date("d/m/Y , h:i:s");
$act = "מחיקת עמוד";
$nameadmin = $rowadmin['firstname'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logs` ( `time` , `act` , `admin`) VALUES ('$time' , '$act' , '$nameadmin') ;")  or die ("$error[errorcoontodb]");

}else{ exit('\$order_id isnt set!'); }

?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I wonder if SO meanwhile made built-in templates for these comments? :)

Comment: Is `$_GET['ID']` set?

Answer (score 2):

Notice the redirect on the second line here?

```
$order_id=$_GET['ID']; 
header("Location: orders.php");
if (isset($order_id)) { 
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `ID`='$order_id'  ");  
$time = date("d/m/Y , h:i:s");
$act = "מחיקת עמוד";
$nameadmin = $rowadmin['firstname'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logs` ( `time` , `act` , `admin`) VALUES ('$time' , '$act' , '$nameadmin') ;")  or die ("$error[errorcoontodb]");

}else{ exit('\$order_id isnt set!'); }
```

You're redirecting to `orders.php` rather than stay on the current page. However, as you don't `exit` the rest of the script still runs, so if `$_GET['ID']` is set then the record should insert. However, if you say that the record *isn't* inserting then it seems likely that `$_GET['ID']` *isn't* set, and so you would get the output `$order_id isnt set!` -- except as you're redirecting before this you never see it (and the same is true if the query is failing).

Remove that `header` and there should be an error message that explains the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$order_id=$_GET['ID']; 
header("Location: orders.php");
if (isset($order_id)) { 
$query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `orders` WHERE `ID`='$order_id'  ");  
$time = date("d/m/Y , h:i:s");
$act = "מחיקת עמוד";
$nameadmin = $rowadmin['firstname'];


mysql_query("INSERT INTO `logs` ( `time` , `act` , `admin`) VALUES ('$time' , '$act' , '$nameadmin') ;")  or die ("$error[errorcoontodb]");

}
```

Please comment the line `header("Location: orders.php");`

And debug the code for any errors messages.
And please put the `header("Location: orders.php");` after executing the queries, and recommendation practice would to exit the code after redirection. `header("Location: orders.php"); exit;`